# FocusRequester / requestFocus inconsistent / Not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, focus

Trying to use the FocusRequester on a Snackbar item and get it to gain focus on entry. But for some reason nothing I’m doing works.

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
val modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester)
Snack(modifier, data)
LaunchedEffect(data) {
    if(data != null) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
        // do stuff
    }
}
FadeInOut(data, content)
```

The above is the gist of the code with not much different than Materials Snackbar iteration. The semantics for Talkback read out correctly, but the focus doesn’t take effect at all. I’m not sure why.